# Could not insert table using radeditor control in IE(9 and 10)

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik, radeditor

I am using rad editor for editing html of one of the module in my project. Everything works perfectly in all browser except IE10(as well as IE9). In IE, i can not insert table object which is given in rad control. also addition of symbol,undo doesn't work.if i click on any of these menus, then editor in design mode is not editable. i need to switch to html mode and then design mode to maker it work again. also the UI seems to be shaking in right side and bottom of editor.

[image: Rad editor issue]

Any help guys.....!!!!

Comment: If you show us the code that leads to the problem we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try their latest version. If yours is old it may not support these browsers.
A workaround for that may be adding an x-ua compatible meta tag to your page to put IE in IE8 mode